# Connection drop with IBM Watson Server

Tags: python, tcp, twisted, ibm-watson

I have been using IBM watson speech to text over websockets and since recently there are connection drops in the middle of process or handshake issues.

This is the error log and it can't process audio files after 1-2 minutes of handshake:
 _connectionLost: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): : Connection was closed cleanly.

('WebSocket connection closed: connection was closed uncleanly (peer dropped the TCP connection without previous WebSocket closing handshake)', 'code: ', 1006, 'clean: ', False)

Can somebody help me understand what is exactly going wrong. I am currently running the process through a virtual machine but the problem persists even with local machine implementation. Is there a problem with Watson server?

Comment: For clarification, are you calling the service through a socket connection in client side javascript?

Comment: I am actually using python for socket connection

Answer (score 2):

That's our fault. We experienced an issue with WebSockets connections being dropped when the service was under heavy load.

Comment: Can you please see if Watson has had any issues in the past week or two that would lead to this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/q/55224041/470749 Or what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan We are investigating this particular issue. We don't think it's a problem with the service but we are going to add some tests to see if connections get dropped after one hour.

Comment: Thanks. My connections seem to get dropped around 1h15m. I'm looking forward to hearing what you discover! Thanks.

Comment: Any update? I even tried sending `\Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\Frame::OP_PING` every 120 seconds, but I still experienced this `Connection closed (1006 - Underlying connection closed)` error after approximately 73 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: We are not able to replicate the issue @Ryan. We can successfully keep a connection open white recognizing a 96MB mp3 file. We are still investigating.